# how can I slove :'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I use the Universal Sentence Encoder for sentence similarity task .
I haved imported :

...
...
..

```
 import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf tf.disable_v2_behavior()
 import tensorflow_hub as hub
 import numpy as np
 import seaborn as sns
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd
 ...
 ...
 ...
similarities_df = pd.DataFrame()
...
...
similarities_df = similarities_df.concat(
 {
   'similarity': cos_theta,
   'message1': messages[i],
   'message2': messages[j], 
 },
 ignore_index = True
    )
```

..
...

when I excute python code in CMD . I see this message. please help me how to solve this error .
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'"

Please tell me how to solve this error ?

Comment: `concat` is not a method of `DataFrame` but a function of `pandas`. So use `pd.concat([df1, df2, ...])`. In your case I think you should simply: `similarities_df = pd.DataFrame({ your_dict })`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 0):

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Use `pandas.concat(...)` in place.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html